# Can't add column to Crate table

Tags: database, elasticsearch, crate

I have an existing table created some time ago. The table is on a Crate cluster with 3 nodes. All notes are running version 0.54.9. When I run the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN size integer
```

I get the following error involving the names of  existing columns:

```
SQLActionException[Merge failed with failures {[mapper [location] of different type, current_type [ip], merged_type [ArrayMapper]]}]
```

The table has an `ARRAY(ip)` column called "locations" but I don't understand how this is related.

When I ran the same command on  a local instance with the same schema, it ran fine. A search online showed that the nearest error like the above that other people have come across has been related to Elasticsearch indexes. This suggests to me that the table (or its mapping in ES) may be corrupt but I'm not sure how to fix that as the cluster is currently in production.

Does anyone have any ideas how one might check / repair this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug at Crate's 0.54 releases. Its already fixed but not yet released, see: https://github.com/crate/crate/commit/6d01cb8a45bb904f45ab1270975ef81e88bf776c

Please be patient, upgrade to 0.55.0 (testing) or build Crate from source by yourself.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you happen to know why this happens? I read the commit linked to but couldn't really get a sense of what is going wrong.